# Check function for UninstallDelete is called upon installation

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm using Inno Setup to make my (un)installer. I want to make possibility to remove some "leftover" files after uninstall optionally, so I use `[UninstallDelete]` section with `Check` function for this. Function returns some value, but also shows some debug message. Something like this:

```pascal
[UninstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{app}\Plugins"; Check: ShouldRemovePlugins

[Code]
//...
var
  DelPlugins: Boolean;
//...
function ShouldRemovePlugins(): Boolean;
var text:string;
begin
  if(DelPlugins = true) then
    text := 'We should remove plugins'
  else
    text := 'We should not remove plugins';
  MsgBox(text, mbInformation, MB_OK);
  Result := DelPlugins;
end;
```

The thing is, that according to message box popping up, function is somehow called on install, not uninstall. So, question is - why so? Is it something about Inno Setup "workflow"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's determined during installation which uninstall tasks (including, but not limited to `UninstallDelete` entries) will be performed on uninstall.

So your `Check` function will indeed by called during installation.

---

See how processing `UninstallDelete` section is [a step of installation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=installorder):

> Once the actual installation process begins, this is the order in which the various installation tasks are performed:
>
> - `[InstallDelete]` is processed.
> - The entries in `[UninstallDelete]` are stored in the uninstall log (which, at this stage, is stored in memory).
> - The application directory is created, if necessary.
> - ...

---

To delete files conditionally during uninstallation you have to code this explicitly in [`CurUninstallStepChanged` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurUninstallStepChanged).

Use `usUninstall` or `usPostUninstall` step.